# How do you append the contents of all the cells in one column with ".jpg"?

Tags: function, append, concatenation, openoffice-calc

For example a cell in column "A" has the text `american-carbide` and I need to append it with ".jpg" for the result of `american-carbide.jpg`?

Answer (score 3):

`=CONCATENATE(A1;".jpg")` should do the trick.

Comment: How about for the entire column B? Thanks.

Comment: Just enter the formula into Cell B1 and copy it down - OpenOffice will automatically change A1 to A2, A3 and so on.